# How to enable dynamic module with an existing NGINX installation

Tags: nginx, configuration, geoip

## Introduction

From NGINX version 1.9.11 and upwarts, a new feature is introduced: dynamic modules. 
With dynamic modules, you can optionally load separate shared object files at runtime as modules – both third-party modules and some native NGINX modules. ([source](https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-modules-nginx-1-9-11/))

## My setup and the problem

I have NGINX installed from the mainline (currently 1.9.14) so it is capable to use dynamic modules. It has also the module I want dynamicly enabled:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.14
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules ... --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic ...
```

Note the `--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic` which loads the module I need (dynamically).
Unfortunately, the documentation is lacking (some details) and I am unable to set this up.
I have an existing NGINX installation (not from source). But so far as I can understand I just need to build the module, place the generated module file in the right NGINX folder and enable it in the config file.

## What I tried so far

I tested this on a different machine (with the same configuration, but not a production machine), but I don't see the `ngx_http_geoip_module.so` file.
The commands I used:

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.9.14/
./configure --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic
```

## The questions

- Is it a problem that I try to build the module on a system that has
  NGINX installed **not** from source?
- Why is there no .so file generated by my commands?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same question, and @vladiastudillo answer was the missing piece I needed.

First add the nginx stable repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

Then run apt update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And get the nginx geoip module:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-module-geoip
```

This will download and load the module to `/usr/lib/nginx/modules`

---

To load the nginx module,

open `nginx.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

add add below in the main context:

```
load_module "modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
```

The module will be loaded, when you reload the configuration or restart nginx.

*To dynamically “unload” a module, comment out or remove its `load_module` directive and reload the nginx configuration.*

Comment: Do I need to reinstall nginx from the ppa? Or is the standard NGINX from Ubuntu sufficient?

Comment: if the NGINX is built with dynamic modules you don't need to reinstall. To check available modules type `nginx -V` and check for the dynamic string.

Comment: Where is the main context?

Comment: @W.M. main context is in the nginx.conf file, without any brackets. add it as the first line.

Comment: did any one get a problem due to version differences i.e., you are running version say 1.13 and the module is compiled against version say 1.17?

Answer (score 8):

Found this to be slightly different on *Amazon Linux 2016.09*, *Amazon Linux 2016.03 after performing yum update.*

You can confirm this ahead of time by using this command on your ec2 instance `sudo yum search nginx-mod-http-geoip` and you will see an `N/S matched: nginx-mod-http-geoip` entry in the response with specifics of `nginx-mod-http-geoip.x86_64 : Nginx HTTP geoip module`

In these cases, the installed nginx version will be `1.10.1`. When this is true, you can simple install the nginx geoip module from Amazon's existing yum repo via:

`sudo yum install nginx-mod-http-geoip`

Then associate the module with your `nginx.conf`  and placing this line in the main context

`include /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf;`

(note this is subtly different from the main answer - in aws you have an entry in nginx.conf pointing to another `*.conf` file which then points to the `*.so` file)

Comment: I think I have a similar issue to yours, but I am hosting with Vultr, and I when I run `nginx -t` I get: `nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1012002 instead of 1014000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1` When I tried your solution, it just said that it was already installed! Any ideas?

Comment: 2018/07/09 09:37:14 [emerg] 9552#0: "load_module" directive is not allowed here in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1

Any ideas why i get this? I followed your steps exactly..

Comment: i need help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243269/nginx-geoip-module-config-issue

Comment: `No package nginx-mod-http-geoip available.` . ? anyone has this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using docker nginx:latest this module is already included in the image as such you only need specify load_module as such:

`"/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";`

You also need to create a geoip folder in your nginx mapped volume.
Though the databases seem to no longer been updated or available and geoip2 modules are not included.  So you many need to google...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, you have to install the http_geoip_module lib for your ubuntu version with:

$ sudo apt-get install nginx-module-geoip

Comment: I tried your command, but I got "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nginx-module-geoip"