# NginX GeoIP Module Config - load_module not allowed on First Line of Conf

Tags: nginx, geoip, nginx-config

My nginx conf looks like this:

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf;

server {

}

server {

}
```

I had installed mod-http-geoip via sudo yum install nginx-mod-http-geoip

and i have these:

/usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:

```
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
```

/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so

The error I get:

2018/07/09 09:37:14 [emerg] 9552#0: "load_module" directive is not allowed here in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1

This is my nginx -V :

```
[root@ip-172-31-45-46 modules]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'
```

Note that the above had "--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic" argument

Can someone point what im missing?

I followed Peter Jones' answer on this post: [How to enable dynamic module with an existing NGINX installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554405/how-to-enable-dynamic-module-with-an-existing-nginx-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also tried:
- Putting load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
 in the first line of my .conf file.
- putting load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
 inside the server { }

All giving me the same error, "load_module" directive is not allowed here

Do I need to run ./configure command, make or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on all the information so far, you have installed nginx from EPEL repository. While there's nothing wrong with that, I would suggest to install it from nginx's own YUM repository as it's:

- coming from the software's developer
- more recent (as I see now the nginx own repo is with 1.14.0 while epel's is on 1.12.2)

So make sure you [install nginx properly](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos-7-properly).

Every nginx distribution tends to have their own convention for structuring files. But nginx configuration rules are the same across the board. So:

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf;
server {

}
server {

}
```

... isn't really possible, as `server` block should go within `http` section.

The `load_module` should be placed at the top level (beginning of the file) within `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

### If you can't move from / want to stick to EPEL's nginx distribution

The EPEL nginx package convention is to include those `load_module` directives from each module's `.conf` file:

```
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
```

After a module is installed, it drops a .conf file with `load_module` to load it.

Make sure that `include` goes at the top of your nginx configuration and not inside any section.

Comment: turns out what i had was a modular conf file within /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/nginx/modules` is really just a symlink to `/usr/lib64/nginx/modules` and Nginx is expecting to find the actual modules in there, not config directives.

Looking at your config above I would expect the path to your config file for dynamic modules to be `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled`, or you can include them in the very top section of your nginx.conf, above the events block.

Comment: but the content of /usr/share/nginx/modules (contains mod-http-geoip.conf)  and /usr/lib64/nginx/modules (contains ngx_http_geoip_module.so)  are not same. NginX complains about the directive load_modules, or does it really mean directory is invalid?

Comment: My bad, didn't notice you are using Red Hat. What happens if you put the load directives in your nginx.conf instead?

Comment: It's giving the same error. So i think the include works as expected, but load_modules is not allowed in there, i've looked around they seem to be placed in the first line, i wonder why it's complaining for me?